# Laravel push Notification using davibennun/laravel-push-notification package

Tags: android, ios, laravel, push-notification, notifications

I am using Laravel 5.2 to sent push notifications to my IOS app using davibennun/laravel-push-notification package

I get below error when I try to sent a push notification

AdapterException in Apns.php line 57:
Certificate /path/to/certificate.pem does not exist

I have given absolute path to certificate. But, it doesn't work

```
'appNameIOS'     => array(
        'environment' =>'development',
        'certificate' => app_path().'/Certificates_d.pem',
        'passPhrase'  =>'password',
        'service'     =>'apns'
    )
```

,

Can anyone please help resolve this issue. Thanks!

Comment: Is the error literally `line 57: Certificate /path/to/certificate.pem does not exist`?

Comment: Yes, where as, the certificate is present on the path. I have verified it. I think it is something to do with SLY push adaptor

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the file permissions for the pem files are (0644), also pem file must be inside app folder here how i set path, normally i keep files in pem directory inside app folder.

'certificate' => app_path()."/pem/apns-pro.pem",

file permissions must be 0644 for the file this is important.